# A small example about using Library Path in flash IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I know how to use Source Path ( which is just an another source folder). But could never figure out how to make use of library path.
Any small written code example over using and understanding this concept would be appreciated.

I know using SWCs too.. but how can i use a bunch of classes which are not in SWC form, in my library path ?

( Additionally , why Flex SDK not included in Source path.. rathar than in library path ?)

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 0):

The library path is for pointing to compiled code sources like SWC files.

Comment: Is flex SDK too a pre compiled source ?

Comment: The Flex SDK includes several compiled sources, for example core.swc, osmf.swc, playerglobal.swc